# Qt: How to repeat sound x times with QtSound

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm not sure I understand correctly how QSound.setLoop function should work.

I want to play some wave file 3 times. Tried the following code but it only plays it once.

```
QSound soundObj(filePath);
soundObj.setLoops(3);
soundObj.play();
```

Help :-)

Edit:
The full version of this code looks like this

```
void Alarms::playSound(QString filePath)
{
    QSound soundObj(filePath);
    soundObj.setLoops(3);
    soundObj.play();
}
```

Comment: That should work just fine. Could you be stopping the sound just shortly after?

Comment: You're right :) my QSound object was destroyed too soon. I used dynamic allocation instead and it works great.

Comment: :) Had to be something like that. Glad it's solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

soundObj object is destroyed to quickly. 
Has to be allocated dynamically.

Comment: Thats right. play returns immediately, so event loop starts to play sounds. If object is destroyed, sounds are stopped also.

Comment: or using: static QSound soundObj(filePath);